JavaScript reduce returning different values
I have an array as follows:
"Totales": [
    {
        "Id": "1",
        "Medio": "Datafono",
        "diferenciaGr": 0.00,
        "diferenciaML": 6000.00
    },
    {
        "Id": "2",
        "Medio": "Efectivo",
        "diferenciaGr": 0.00,
        "diferenciaML": 165000.00
    },
    {
        "Id": "3",
        "Medio": "Credito",
        "diferenciaGr": 0.00,
        "diferenciaML": 0.00
    },
    {
        "Id": "4",
        "Medio": "Transferencias",
        "diferenciaGr": 0.00,
        "diferenciaML": 0.00
    }

I need to sum the last two fields: diferencaML and diferenciaGr.
For this, I am using reduce()
 determinarBalance: function (balance) {
        var cobranzasModel = this.getView().getModel("CobranzasSet"),
            data = this.getView().getModel("CobranzasSet").getData();

        let difML = data.Totales.reduce(function (dif, c) {
            return dif + c.diferenciaML
        })
        let difGr = data.Totales.reduce(function (dif, c) {
            return dif + c.diferenciaGr
        })

        console.log(difML);
        console.log(difGr);

        return (balance);
    },

But for some reason both reduce functions are returning the following results:
[object Object]16500000
[object Object]000

Given the data above, the results should be 171000.00 and 0.00.
So, reduce it is not paying any attention to decimal point, plus adding [object Object] at the beginning.  Any clues about this odd behaviour?

You need to supply an initial accumulator value as the second argument to reduce(). Otherwise it uses the first element of the array as the initial value, so the first value of dif is an object, not a number.

So use an initial value 0.

FWIW, this is not JSON; it's an array of objects. JSON is a string.

You need to set each reduce's initial value to 0.
let difML = data.Totales.reduce(function (dif, c) {
    return dif + c.diferenciaML
}, 0) // change is here
let difGr = data.Totales.reduce(function (dif, c) {
    return dif + c.diferenciaGr
}, 0) // change is here

otherwise, it will use the first item itself (not just it's .diferenciaML/.diferenciaGr) as the initial value, then converting everything to strings since you can't add an object and a number (and then, you can't add a string and number (without an implicit cast of the number to a string))

Thanks a lot, worked as a charm!!!  This was my first time using reduce.  I thought that as a the first argument was being defined at that precise moment, by that was also being set to 0 initially.  Lesson learned

Some small annotations:

Wording:
In fact, you take the total of a single property, not the difference, which is not given and usually take by substraction from a value.

Syntax:
Array#reduce takes  either the first and second item of the array for the first iteration or only the first item along with an initialValue. By having properties, you need to start with value zero.

Reusability:
By taking nearly the same code for getting a total value, you could hand over the property and get a total of all same named poperty of all objects in an array.
const
    getTotal = (array, property) => array.reduce((total, object) => total + object[property], 0),

    // usage
    totalML = getTotal(data.Totales, 'diferenciaML'),
    totalGr = getTotal(data.Totales, 'diferenciaGr');




Thanks Nina!! About the wording comment, I omitted the context on my question, but difference fields where calculated previously.  All I need at this time is to understand that difference fields are greater than 0.
As for Syntax, this was my first time using reduce, so I do appreciate your help on letting me understand this better
And for the last, I do like the "economics" on code lines, Your suggestion is clearly smaller, so I will give it a try
